# DB name not showing Mongo DB until we insert at least one document

Tags: mongodb

I am very curious to know why mydb(database) name not listed out when we used **show dbs** command after **use mydb** command (please find the below commands)

```
command : use mydb

output : switched to db mydb

command: show dbs
```

output: it's listed all the available DB names except mydb.

mydb listed only after insert one document into mydb.

Any idea why mydb database not listed until we insert document into DB?

Comment: [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_create_database.htm) mongo db beginner guide explain very well .

Comment: To save you reading promoted links the reason is because creationis lazy. In other words is only happens when you actually insert/remove/update documents

Comment: @yogesh actually that link is incorrect in saying "The command will create a new database, if it doesn't exist otherwise it will return the existing database." by default it does not

Comment: @Sammaye and also mentioned this **Your created database (mydb) is not present in list. To display database you need to insert atleast one document into it.** :)

Comment: thanks Sammaye. is there any reason behind it? not to show mydb until you do any CUD operation?

Comment: thanks @yogesh. i gone through this document. but it not explained why it's behaving?. that's why i posted question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation of "databases" or indeed "collections" as "physical resources" is an attribute of MongoDB that is basically implemented "by design".

Until there is some "actual data" in any "namespace" then the core code makes sure that there is no "physical" resource that reflects the selected namespace until the prime objective of "stored data" is met.

This means something stupid such as:

```js
use non-existent
```

Does not actually create a useless resource in "physical" storage and as such does not respond to "listing" commands, since those really only make sense with "real" and "physical" resources.

I think that on further analysis that this approach makes a lot of sense, and as such is the way in which this is implemented.